# NEventStore with multiple producers

Tags: concurrency, event-sourcing, neventstore

If I have a load-balanced application that can be scaled to 2 or more instances, and each of those instances can commit events for the same NEventStore aggregate, will I run into ordering/race condition problems?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a unique index in the Commits table on BucketId, StreamId, and Commit Sequence.  If two different instances of an application tried to commit changes to the same aggregate at the same time, the second one would receive a concurency exception, which could be handled.  See more in this article:  http://burnaftercoding.com/post/play-with-neventstore/